# How do I debug in IE if there are no errors being thrown?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

I am finding it impossible to debug for IE. (Multiple versions, I'm using version 11, someone else has used 7, requirements are to support 9+) This is because there seem to be no errors thrown at all in the console. Some parts of the page simply do not load. When there was a similar error in firefox an error was thrown that gave me some clue as to what was wrong. Maybe I'm not using the developer tools correctly, but under console everything seems fine, it's just that the page is broken.

Comment: when the tools wont help you can only rely on traditional debugging, comment out step by step etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things that you can do to help your life:

**Try a `console.log` wrapper**

Most versions of IE crash and burn if there is a `console.log` statement and the console isn't open.  Things simply fail silently.  I'd recommend a wrapper, something like this one: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/

**Use `window.onerror`**

`window.onerror` is a bit hacky, but it can sometimes really help.  This might point you in a useful direction:   http://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/how-to-catch-javascript-errors-with-window-onerror-even-on-chrome-and-firefox/

**Add an `alert` at the beginning of each file to make sure it is loaded and run.**

Using an alert can help let you know if there is a syntax error loading a file.

Answer (score 0):

As I am a Linux user I can not directly test it. But in most Browsers there is a certain *debug* Statement, that you can insert in the code. And the second posibility should be opening the Developer Tools from the Browsers menu.

See [Debugger Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/0bwt76sk%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) at MSDN